# Created perspectives in SSAS tabular don't appear

Tags: ssas-tabular, ssas-2016

I am trying to create perspectives in a SSAS Tabular mode cube in Visual Studio 2013. But the problem is that the created perspective doesn’t appear when I click on OK. I have tried it several times, and each time with another selection of tables. Also creating a new Visual Studio solution and retry it didn’t help. I couldn't find any known errors on Google about this issue.

Is there a hidden feature that hides the created perspective or something?

I hope that you guys can help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not using VS2015 or VS2017RC?

Comment: There used to be a bug that you had to deploy and process a model before the perspectives appeared, if I recall right. It is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! I installed VS2015 including SSDT, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried to create the perspective in the existing solution and in a new test solution. Both solutions showed the same behavior: they don't save and disappear after clicking on OK. Also re-opening/rebuilding the solution didn't help..